# Can I just STOP SqlServer replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

I'm running 12 sql server replications, 11 of which have 1 subscription, and 1 has 2 subscriptions.

Now I have a problem with a very large transaction log which I want to shrink, but I get the messages that the transaction log that is in use.

I suspect that the replication (publication, maybe the subscription too) is causing this problem.

Now the only way I found to stop publication does DROP all thee publications, but that is something more than what I wanted: to pause the publication.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Simple or Full recovery for the DB in question?

Comment: i still haven't found a way :(

Answer (score 1):

Pausing replication won't accomplish what you want.  When you have replication turned on, those log records which are of interest to replication (i.e. those for objects that you have configured to replicate) will not be marked as reusable until they're at the distributor.  The only two ways to "pause" replication would be to stop either the log reader or the distribution agent, neither of which gets those log records to the distributor.  To see if replication is your problem, check the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases for your database and see what it says.  If it's "replication", then replication is your problem. :)  If it is, how far behind is your log reader agent?

Comment: Can you clarify this sentence: *"The only two ways to pause replication would be to stop either the log reader or the distribution agent, **neither of which** gets those log records to the distributor."*  Are you saying that stopping either of these agents will or won't pause replication?

Comment: Stopping either agent will prevent commands from flowing from the publisher to the distributor. Stopping the log reader agent will prevent publisher → distributor traffic. This has the side effect of making the transaction log at the publisher grow as one of the conditions for clearing log records is "has this been processed by the log reader agent?". Stopping the distribution agent will stop distributor → subscriber traffic. This is less dangerous but be aware of what your retention is at the distributor; if you pause it for more than the minimum retention, you'll have to re-initialize.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much.  It seems to be very difficult to find this information on MSDN.